# How to tokenize a single column in a CSV file with 2 columns using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, tokenize

I am trying to perform a sentiment analysis using a Bayesian Classifier and I have a CSV file consisting of rows with the following structure:

```
Column 1: Either 1 or 0 
Column 2: String 

Example: 1 | This is a great movie
```

I am using Pandas when reading the CSV file (read_csv).

After reading each row from the CSV file has the following structure:

```
1;This is a great movie
0;This is a bad movie
```

I would like to tokenize each string in column 2. However, I have not managed to do this. How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: is every row a list? as shown?

Comment: No my mistake! I do believe read_csv returns a DataFrame or TextParser. Changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the df looks like (just replace column name from 0 to `column_name` which you have as header:

```
                        0
0  1;This is a great movie
1    0;This is a bad movie

pd.DataFrame(df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split(";")).values.tolist(),columns=['A','B'])
   A                      B
0  1  This is a great movie
1  0    This is a bad movie
```

Comment: If I use this given code snippet I get an error message that talks about 
**pandas/core/- frame, generic, internals, indexes/base and pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item.** Ends with **KeyError: 0.** The whole error message is to long for a comment.

Comment: That is because you have not replace the code snippet with your header name, replace `df[0].apply(..)` with `df['col'].apply(..)` where `col` is the name of the header which you see when you print your dataframe df.